# Does the UserName field have to be unique to work properly with ASP.NET MVC's SimpleMembership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I am making an app using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework with Code First migrations.
In the class called `InitializeSimpleMembership`, there is the following line of code:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", 
    "UserId",   "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Where `"UserName"` refers to the column that contains the Users' usernames. Do these usernames have to be unique? I use OAuth authentication through Facebook solely in this app. So, in the UserName field, I store the user's Facebook name (e.g. "George Smith"). Obviously there can be many George Smiths that use my app, will this cause any conflicts?

I have noticed that many methods of the `WebSecurity` class, such as `WebSecurity.GetUserId` take the following parameter: `string userName`. If usernames are *not* unique, then I'm not sure how that would work. Additionally, the default FacebookClient for OAuth returns an ExtraData dictionary that would contain, for example, `ExtraData["username"] = george.smith@gmail.com`. Seems like they want to store emails under UserName (in order for UserNames to be unique).

I don't have a very thorough understanding of SimpleMembership. Can somebody clarify for me whether or not the values stored under UserName should be unique for everything to work smoothly?

Thank you.

Comment: This may help you http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: That was useful, thanks. He (or rather Matthew Osborn) mentions that "All SimpleMembership requires is that there are two columns on your users table so that we can hook up to it – an “ID” column and a “username” column." Thats awesome, and I understand that, but still no info on whether the "username" column needs to be unique.

Comment: It should be unique for all the functionality to work correctly, As far i know everyone design `schema` where the `username` column will be `unique`. May be an expert here will answer you more technically.

Comment: I think I'm going to make the username column unique simply to avoid possible complications in the future. However, I found the [SQL Table definition for SimpleMembership in .NET 4.5](https://gist.github.com/3419405), and [UserName] is not marked with unique.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out from looking at he code, the username has to be unique. In the end it is quite reasonable: think of a login system that allows for non-unique usernames, how would the system distinguish the users? You can't rely on a different password, as this would be the only difference when the username is the same.
If you want to show another name on the page instead of the "real" (unique) username, e.g. some kind of additional nickname or screen name, you should create a CustomMembershipProvider and use your own user table. That way you can customize everything to meet your requirements. That would allow for hundreds of "Bob"s with a unique username each.